# Why is my unicode character (❤) displaying as 'd in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

Apologies if this is a really basic question.

I'm trying to print a Unicode heart symbol ❤

When I run in my terminal on Visual Code Studio, the ❤ appears fine but when I try it anywhere else, all  I see is: 'd

```
heart_symbol = u'\u2764'
print(heart_symbol)
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: It depends on your operating system and the underlying encoding. I just ran those two lines in my terminal and it printed out a heart.

Comment: `u'\u2764'` => `0x27` and `0x64`, `0x27` == `'` and `0x64` == `d`

Comment: It probably also depends on on font availability

Comment: @NickA More specifically, the UTF-16-BE encoding of U+2764 is `\x27\x64`.

Comment: I am not sure if you actually use unicode...